# LSTM after CNN how to feed in and what dimensions (input size)?

Tags: audio, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to build a Convolutional Recurrent Network that takes a fixed input size of 32000 x 1 raw audio time series. It's just a numpy array of length 32000. So for example if we have a batch size of 1, my dimensions would be

```
torch.size([1,32000,1])
```

1 audio time series, 32000 in length, 1 channel

I had to reshape that to be

```
torch.size([1,1,32000])
```

so that it could be fed into the convolutional layer

As this is fed into Convolutional / Pooling layers my dimensions change as follows

```
torch.Size([1, 1, 32000])
torch.Size([1, 64, 7981])
torch.Size([1, 64, 1995])
torch.Size([1, 64, 1993])
torch.Size([1, 64, 498])
torch.Size([1, 128, 496])
torch.Size([1, 128, 494])
torch.Size([1, 128, 123])
torch.Size([1, 256, 121])
torch.Size([1, 256, 119])
torch.Size([1, 256, 29])
torch.Size([1, 512, 27])
torch.Size([1, 512, 25])
torch.Size([1, 512, 6])
```

So after the final max pooling layer, the size of the data is

```
torch.Size([1, 512, 6])
```

How do I go about this output and take it into the LSTM?

How would we feed this result into the LSTM? would it involve flattening our output from the last max pooling layer? Or is the input size for the LSTM going to be 512 or 6?

Please advise and thank you.

LSTM expects a 3D input shape of #Samples (audio time series), # Time steps (32000) , # features

Answer (score 0):

Adding an LSTM on top of the CNN here doesn’t make sense. You’ve already used the CNN to learn features based on the time dimension, so using an LSTM on top to try and learn the relationship over time of the CNN features that represent the relationship over time doesn’t make sense.

You use an LSTM on top of a CNN when you’re using the CNN to learn the spatial dimensions, then the LSTM to learn the time dimension. For example video classification where you can use a CNN to learn features from each image, then an LSTM that takes those features as input and learns features over time.